# Can't download Facebook user profile picture via Android

Tags: android, facebook

My problem is that, I am not able to download user profile picture via ID. I am able to get user profile picture when i use browser and this URL :

http://graph.facebook.com/janno.hindrekson/picture?type=small

I am able to see this users profile picture:
[image]

But when i want to get this picture via Android, I am not able

```
    // Execute the task
    new LoadImage().execute("http://graph.facebook.com/janno.hindrekson/picture?type=small");


}

private class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(TESTPROFILEPICT.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Image ....");
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... args) {
        try {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(args[0]).getContent());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap image) {
        if (image != null) {
            fbUserAvatar.setImageBitmap(image);
            pDialog.dismiss();
        } else {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(TESTPROFILEPICT.this, "Image Does Not exist or Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

So any ideas ? How i should download profile pictures via Android?

Thanks, 
Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Android, there is an easier way to complete this task provided that you can import the Facebook SDK into your project.

There is a method inside the SDK called Profile.getProfilePictureUri(int, int):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/Profile/

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue. Try to replace the name with the respective facebookId.

```
new LoadImage().execute("http://graph.facebook.com/100001997422983/picture?type=small");
```

**Edit**

I recognized this question was asked several times on stackoverflow.

Anyway, the reason is, that facebook redirects that url. Therefore you have to call the redirected url. 
This is a pretty good example:

http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-httpurlconnection-follow-redirect-example/

Or you have to use the Facebook API:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/

I chose the redirect-method, because it's universal, and you can fetch images from all over the internet.